# Repeatation Of Ajax(Jquery method) Submission on a single click And Image Not Passing to server

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having issues on submmiting a formdata to my server after a jquery based client side validation. i havebeen working on this since noon, i really need assistance.I had made a jquery slider with my login form, so after each input it slides to the next after validation, so i have two issues basically, **one** after each submit of a review.. 5 reviews are actually made, and **two** the image is not processed, i'm not certain it passes to my server because it is not saved on my harddrive.

**Here Is My Simple HTml Form**

```
 <form action="review.php" method="post" id="makeReview" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- first slide start -->
<div class="makereview firstSlide">
<div id="myslides" > 
 <input type="text" id="reviewName"  name="reviewName"  placeholder="Name of Reviewee" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9'.- ]+" maxlength="25" class="myForm">
 <br>
<button class="btn btn-info nextSlideOne" >
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<br>
 <strong style="color: red;text-align: left;" class="errorOne"></strong>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- first slide ends-->

<!-- Second slide start -->
<div class="makereview secondSlide">
<div id="myslides">

 <input type="text" id="reviewLink"  name="reviewLink" placeholder="https://reviewee.com" pattern="[a-zA-Z/.0-9:]+" class="myForm" style="text-transform: lowercase;">
 <br>
 <button class="btn btn-info nextSlideTwo" >
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<br>
 <strong style="color: red;text-align: left;" class="errorTwo"></strong>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second slide ends-->

<!-- third slide start -->
<div class="makereview thirdSlide">
<div id="myslides">

 <input type="file" class="myForm" name="image" id="reviewLogo" style="margin: auto">
 <br>
 <button class="btn btn-info nextSlideThree" >
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<br>
 <strong style="color: red;text-align: left;" class="errorThree"></strong>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- third slide ends-->

<!-- fourth slide start -->
<div class="makereview fourthSlide">
<div id="myslides" >
<h3>Your Review</h3>
  <textarea class="myForm" name="reviewBody" minlength="200" maxlength="500" placeholder="Your review. minimum 200 Characters and maximum 500 Characters" rows="8" id="reviewBody" ></textarea>
 <br>
<button class="btn btn-info nextSlideFour">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
</button>
<br>
 <strong style="color: red;text-align: left;" class="errorFour"></strong>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- fourth slide ends-->
<div class="makereview fifthSlide">
<div id="myslides" >
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-large nextSlideFive">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i> Verify And Submit
</button>
<br>
 <br>
 <h2 style="color:green;text-align: center;font-family: serif;" class="responseSuccess"></h2>
 <strong style="color:red;text-align: center;" class="responseError"></strong>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

ANd here is my ajax method in jquery(i extracted it from the larger code to aid reading), the larger code is below it

```
  $(nextFive).click(function(){
$(nextFive).fadeOut('linear')
var formData = $(form).serialize();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'review.php',
      data: formData,
    })
  .done(function() {
      $('.responseSuccess').text('Thank You \n Your Review Have Been Made');
    })
})
```

Here is the larger code(i don't think it's necessary here but for clarity)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  // get the form
$('.scriptOnlyForm').css('visibility','visible')
  var form = $('#makeReview');
// get the buttons 
  var nextOne   = $('.nextSlideOne');
  var nextTwo   = $('.nextSlideTwo');
  var nextThree = $('.nextSlideThree');
  var nextFour  = $('.nextSlideFour');
  var nextFive  = $('.nextSlideFive');
//get the input fie;ds
  var inputOne   = $('#reviewName');
  var inputTwo   = $('#reviewLink');
  var inputThree = $('#reviewLogo');
  var inputFour = $('#reviewBody');
//get the divs
  var first   = $('.firstSlide');
  var second  = $('.secondSlide');
  var third   = $('.thirdSlide');
  var fourth  = $('.fourthSlide');
  var fifth   = $('.fifthSlide');
// get the error classess
  var errorOne   = $('.errorOne');
  var errorTwo   = $('.errorTwo');
  var errorThree = $('.errorThree');
  var errorFour  = $('.errorFour');
// by default slide up all divs except first div
$(second).slideUp('fast');
$(third).slideUp('fast');
$(fourth).slideUp('fast');
$(fifth).hide('fast');

$(nextOne).css('visibility','visible');
$(nextTwo).css('visibility','visible');
$(nextThree).css('visibility','visible');
$(nextFour).css('visibility','visible');

//start the submit fuction  
$(form).submit(function(e){
  // prevent form from submiting by default
  e.preventDefault()
// first slide work========================================================== starts


 $(nextOne).click(function(){
   if($('#reviewName').val() == ''){
   $(errorOne).html('Input The reviewee Name Please');
  $(inputOne).css('background','red');
  return false; 
 }
 else if($('#reviewName').val() != ''){
      $(first).slideUp('slow');
      $(second).slideDown('linear');  
 }
})

//first slide work============================================================  ends


// second slide work========================================================== starts

$pattern_1 = /^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i;
  $pattern_2 = /^(www)((\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i;

 $(nextTwo).click(function(){
   if($('#reviewLink').val() == ''){
   $(errorTwo).html('Input The reviewee Website Url Please');
  $(inputTwo).css('background','red');
  return false;
 }

  if(!$pattern_1.test($('#reviewLink').val()) || !$pattern_2.test($('#reviewLink').val())){
    $(errorTwo).html('Input A Valid Url Of the reviewee Please');
    return false;
  }

 else if($('#reviewLink').val() != ''){
      $(second).slideUp('slow');
      $(third).slideDown('linear');    
 }
})
// second slide work============================================================  ends
// Third slide work========================================================== starts

    $(nextThree).click(function(){

 if($('#reviewLogo').val() == ''){

  $(errorThree).html('Input The reviewee Logo Or badge Please');
  $(inputThree).css('background','red');
  return false;
}else if($('#reviewLogo').val() != ''){
      $(third).slideUp('slow');
      $(fourth).slideDown('linear');
    }
})


// third slide work============================================================  ends


// fourth slide work========================================================== starts


  $(nextFour).click(function(){
if($('#reviewBody').val() == ''){
  $(errorFour).html('Write Your Review Please');
  $(inputFour).css('background','red');
  return false;
 }else if($('#reviewBody').val() != ''){
      $(fourth).slideUp('slow');
      $(fifth).slideDown('linear');

     }
 })

// fourth slide work============================================================  ends

// verify form================================start

$(nextFive).click(function(){
$(nextFive).fadeOut('linear')
var formData = $(form).serialize();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'review.php',
      data: formData,
  })
  .done(function() {
      $('.responseSuccess').text('Thank You \n Your Review Have Been Made');
    })
})
//verify form ================================== ends
})
})
</script>
```

Finally here is my php(it works well when i use a regular form with inputs and submit button, so i guess i problem don't lie here)

```
<?php 
    require 'header.php';
 ?>

<?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $reviewBody = review($_POST['reviewBody']);
    $reviewName = sanitizeString($_POST['reviewName']);
    $reviewLink= sanitizeString($_POST['reviewLink']);
      $reviewDate = date('Y-m-d');
      if(isset($_SESSION['firstname']) && isset($_SESSION['lastname'])){
         $reviewBy=$_SESSION['firstname'].' '. $_SESSION['lastname']; 
      }else{
         $reviewBy= "source-research_user_not_registered_hence_we_give_an_unimaginable_name_that_is_obviously_not_going_to_be_hacked_nor_found_by_anyone";
      }


    if(empty($reviewBody) || empty($reviewName) || empty($reviewLink)){
      die('Input all fields to make a review'); }
        else if(
        $reviewName && $reviewBody && $reviewLink){

          $sql = ("INSERT INTO `reviews` (reviewName, reviewBody ,reviewDate, reviewLink,reviewLike, reviewUnlike, reviewBy ) VALUES ('$reviewName', '$reviewBody' , '$reviewDate','$reviewLink', 0,0, '$reviewBy') ");
          $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
if(!$query) {
header('location:makreview.php');
}


if($query){
  $my = ("SELECT * FROM reviews where reviewName ='$reviewName' and reviewBody='$reviewBody' ");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $my);

if(!$result){
   $sql = ( "DELETE FROM `reviews` WHERE `reviews`.`reviewName` = '$reviewName' AND `reviewBody` = '$reviewBody'");
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
header('LOcation:dashboard.php');
}

if($result->num_rows){
  $row =$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $reviewId=$row['reviewId'];
}

if(!$result->num_rows){
   $sql = ( "DELETE FROM `reviews` WHERE `reviewName` = '$reviewName' AND `reviewBody` = '$reviewBody'");
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   die('could not process, <a href="makereview.php">Go back</a>');
}
}
   }


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && isset($reviewId)){
$saveto = "reviews/".$reviewId.".jpg";
 $space='[\s]';
  $nospace='';
  $saveto = preg_replace($space,$nospace,$saveto);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
$typeok = TRUE;
switch($_FILES['image']['type'])
{
case "image/gif": $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;
case "image/jpeg": // Both regular and progressive jpegs
case "image/pjpeg": $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;
case "image/png": $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;
default: $typeok = FALSE; break;
}
if ($typeok)
{
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);
$max = 900;
$tw = $w;
$th = $h;
}
if ($w > $h && $max < $w)
{
$th = $max / $w * $h;
$tw = $max;
}
elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)
{
$tw = $max / $h * $w;
$th = $max;
}
elseif ($max < $w)
{
$tw = $th = $max;
}
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
imageconvolution($tmp, array(array(-1, -1, -1),
array(-1, 16, -1), array(-1, -1, -1)), 8, 0);
imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($src);
}

if(!file_exists($saveto) && !isset($reviewId)){
  $sql = ( "DELETE FROM `reviews` WHERE `reviews`.`reviewName` = '$reviewName' AND `reviewBody` = '$reviewBody'");
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
header('Location:dashboard.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue,

first you need to note that you cannot submit image with ajax using form serialize. You need to replace 
`var formData = $(form).serialize();`
with 
`var formData = new FormData(this);`

Your form submit ajax code becomes

```
$(nextFive).click(function(){
$(nextFive).fadeOut('linear')
//var formData = $(form).serialize();
var formData = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'review.php',
    data: formData,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
  })
  .done(function() {
      $('.responseSuccess').text('Thank You \n Your Review Have Been Made');
    })
})
```

In your PHP page "review.php", you can only retrieve your form element with `$_POST`, the uploaded image can be retrieved with `$_FILES`. You also need to use PHP's [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to save the file to your desired location from the temporary directory.

Hope this helps. There are several solutions on this online

Comment: Hello, thanks. but still dosen't work. i did as you said
and yes i used the move_uploaded_file,

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are doing and what exactly the issue you still experienced. I have used this code severally and also tested it on your code and I was able to retrieve the image. In your *review.php* file, can you add `print_r($_FILES); exit();` and provide me with the output. It should be an array of the file you uploaded. Paste the out here so I can assist

Comment: On second thought, in addition to the javascript adjustment in my answer, you can also check the permission of the directory it is writing the file to. The Apache user `apache` on CentOS and `www-data` on debian should have write access to that directory for the file to be able to save. But avoid `777` permission by all means

Comment: On using this var formData = new FormData(this);
the data isn't processed i get output of undefined index reviewBody.
what i have in my review.php is

`$reviewBody = review($_POST['reviewBody']);
    $reviewName = sanitizeString($_POST['reviewName']);
    $reviewLink= sanitizeString($_POST['reviewLink']);`

Comment: Can you paste the new ajax submit of your code after adding new FormData(this)? let me review it.

Comment: Works perfect thanks.. I had to place my `var formData = new FormData(this)` just after my `$(form).submit(function(){
})`